# How to minimize number of queries when adding/updating a row in a table with foreign keys

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm pretty new to the SQL and I have some troubles using foreign keys in my table — it takes a lot of queries to insert/update a single row of such table.

So, basically I have a structure of 4 tables which I use to store "key = value" relation for IRC channels:

```
msg
  -id integer //primary key
  -srv_id     //integer
  -chan_id    //integer
  -usr_id     //integer
  -key        //text
  -value      //text
```

.

```
srv
  -id   //integer primary key
  -name //text
```

.

```
chan
  -id   //integer primary key
  -name //text
```

.

```
usr
  -id   //integer primary key
  -name //text
```

srv_id, chan_id and usr_id in msg table are foreign keys from next three tables.

I need to note that users are allowed to overwrite other's keys, so when user is adding a "key = value" relation I need either to insert new row in msg table or update existing value and usr_name for given srv_name, chan_name and key.

**Question**: how do I efficiently add a row (or update it if the given key already exist in msg table) knowing: msg.key = 'some_msg_key', msg.value = 'new_msg_value', srv.name = 'some_srv_name', chan.name = 'some_chan_name' and usr.name = 'some_usr_name' that might not be in the tables yet.

Right now I'm doing something like this:

```
SELECT id FROM srv WHERE name = 'some_srv_name'
```

check if I got id, if not I do

```
INSERT INTO srv WHERE name = 'some_srv_name'
```

and then I get it's id with

```
SELECT id FROM srv WHERE name = 'some_srv_name'
```

then I do the same for chan table and for usr table.
it's 9 queries when the srv, chan and urs names are totally new. isn't it horrible? and that is not the end — my goal is to add new row to the msg table or update it if it exists (based on the key value).

so, when I know that 'some_srv_name', 'some_chan_name' and 'some_usr_name' are in tables and I got their ids, I check if there exists a row with such ids and key value = 'some_msg_key':

```
SELECT id FROM msg WHERE srv_id = 'id_from_previous_queries' AND chan_id = 'id_from_previous_queries' AND key = 'some_msg_key'
```

if I get anything, I know that the row exists and I need to update it, so I do:

```
UPDATE msg SET usr_id = 'id_from_previous_queries', key = 'some_msg_key', value = 'new_msg_value' WHERE id = 'id_from_right_above'
```

if I get nothing, I know that there is no such row and I need to insert it:

```
INSERT INTO msg VALUES(null, 'id_from_previous_queries', 'id_from_previous_queries', 'id_from_previous_queries', 'some_msg_key', 'new_msg_value')
```

So, in total I do 5-11 queries.

I wonder if there is a better way with less number of queries to add/update a row in msg table knowing only names of srv, chan and usr that might not be in tables yet.

Note: I use SQLite

Comment: okay, someone told me about INSERT OR REPLACE INTO, that would definitely help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this more easily.  First build the lookup tables and then the final msg table.  Say you have non-normalized data in a table, src, and you want to insert it.

First, you have to insert new values into each lookup table, using queries such as:

```
insert into srv(name)
    select distinct name
    from src
    where name not in (select name from srv)
```

The id should be assigned automatically by declaring it to be an auto increment/identity/serial column (depending on your database).

Do this for each lookup table.  Then do the following to insert into the msg table:

```
insert into msg(srv_id, chan_id, usr_id, key, value)
    select srv.srv_id, chan.chan_id, . . . 
    from src join
         srv
         on src.name = srv.src_name join
         chan
         on chan.name = srv.chan_name . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to change the value of a primary key. You should look-up how to work with stored procedure and triggers.

Comment: i'm not changing values of primary keys.