# Populate table with all foreign keys from other table's primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, django, oracle, bulkinsert

I'm working on a Django application and created a new table `tblA` which has a foreign key that is linked to the primary key of `tblB`.

Now `tblB` already has several entries (and thus several primary keys in it already).

I want to run an SQL query that will create a new row for every primary key in `tblA` inside `tblB` with the corresponding foreign key copied and default values of all other columns in `tblB` inserted in the rows.

I hope I was clear enough!

Comment: This might answer your question . . . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397273/how-to-minimize-number-of-queries-when-adding-updating-a-row-in-a-table-with-for/11397510#11397510.

Answer (score 0):

you have forgot to paste your table structure .. I am considering as below-

tblA
(
aCol1_PK (primary key),
acol2_desc (description)
)

as of now just take an example of two columns only.

Now for table B

tblB
(
bCol1,
bCol2,
bCol3_FK (foreign key)
)

Now let say you have default values as -

bCol1 - "B_Col1_default_val"
bcol2 - "B_Col2_default_val"

for this situation if you want to insert rows for p_key from table A which is not present in Table B, you can try below query -

```
insert into tblB(col1,col2,col3) 
 ( select 'b_col_default_val','b_col_default_val', acol1_pk 
     from tbla a 
    where a.acol1_pk not in ( select b.bcol3_fk from tblb b))
```

if you want to insert one row for all the primary key value present in table A then -

```
insert into tblB(col1,col2,col3) 
 ( select 'b_col_default_val','b_col_default_val', acol1_pk 
     from tbla a )
```

I hope it will help you .. 
if you require any clarification you can ask/comment.